# Elements overflowing on right side for some time?

Tags: html, css

Im working on a gadget site.So i have to display 10 items on page.

My problem is whenever my page loads,item 2 floats on the right side of item 1 for some time then it appears correctly on left side.It happens for the rest of the items.I want all items to left at once.

See demo so you will get idea what im saying. 
Demo [here.](https://thegeeked.in/best-mobiles-under-10000/)
Also attached my CSS.

What are some corrections i should make?

```css
.article-number{
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.article-item-title{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: auto;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.article_media{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.article-container{
 border: 1px dotted #ccc;
 height: 170px;
 width: 270px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 30px; 
 margin-left: 10px;

}
.specification{
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: none;
  width: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff3800;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.specification a{
  color: #ffffff;
}
#article-flipkart-icon{
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.affiliate-link{
  width: 145px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background: #289dcc;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.affiliate-link a{
  color: #ffffff;
}
#article-amazon-icon{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.article-wrapper{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.article-item-one,.article-item-two,.article-item-three,.article-item-four,.article-item-five,.article-item-six,.article-item-seven,.article-item-eight,.article-item-nine,.article-item-ten{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.featured-image{
  border: 1px dotted;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because all images are rendering after some time.
 There can be multiple solutions to this problem.
1. You can set image width in pixels (300px in your case). - By this,  right content will be at proper position until images appears.
2. You can use a very low-quality image for all item list as a placeholder and later replace image src with proper image URL. - By this, placeholder image will render quickly and it will occupy the required space until proper image appears.